# Extracting data from text

Tags: excel, date, text

I am trying to convert text using only Excel data manipulation functions (not Data/Text to Columns).

Column A looks like this:

```
A1: 10 11 03,-690000,100.163685 
A2: 14 11 03,-761000,100.3977
A3: 17 11 03,-682000,100.575887
```

and so on.

I'd like to get the date (`01 11 03` recognised as a date) in column B, the middle data (between the two commas) in column C and the data on the right (after the second comma) in column D using the full accuracy displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have options that would be easier, but please try in B1:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,2)&"/"&MID(A1,4,2)&"/"&MID(A1,7,2))
```

in C1:

```
=1*MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,FIND(",",MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,99))-1)
```

in D1:

```
=1*MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)+1,99)
```

and copy down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way for you to handle this situation is to simply save your current worksheet as a text file, and then reopen it in Excel.  When you open the file again in Excel it should automatically separate out the three columns the way you want it.  Here is a screen capture from my Excel after I have done this:

[image]

Next you can format the `A` column as a date however you wish.